# html listbox with Vertical scrollbar

Tags: html

I want to create listbox in webpage .
the listbox whould have a vertical scrollbar; but only one item should be alowed to select;

i can get this kind of listbox with  applepineapplemango   this gives me exactlyy a listbox with vertical scrollbar, when no of items in list box are too many. but it allows to select multiple items. i want only one item to get selected

Thanks for any help or suggestions in advance

Comment: title incorrectly says "horizontaL" instead of vertical.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<select size="5">
    <option value="1">Item #1</option>
    <option value="2">Item #2</option>
    <option value="3">Item #3</option>
    <option value="4">Item #4</option>
    <option value="5">Item #5</option>
    <option value="6">Item #6</option>
    <option value="7">Item #7</option>
</select>
```

Live example of this: http://jsfiddle.net/B4RNr/

Comment: @Parag sometimes the most simple things evade us... :)

Comment: (8 years later) Can the size of the listbox somehow be set to "however much fills up the vertical space in the container?"

Comment: @ILikeFood I don't understand what you mean. Example please, or  a mockup?

Comment: I just posted a separate question and answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55930550/dynamically-sized-html-listbox/55930551#55930551 but thanks for your initial answer here -- have an upvote!

Comment: @ILikeFood oh, I see now. Cheers! :) (and BTW... I also like food very much... ;))

Comment: just set the style hight prooperty in css