# dynamically-sized HTML listbox

Tags: html

In HTML, it is possible to render a select element as a "listbox", where the user can pick items from a list rather than from the dropdown, by setting the element's "size" attribute. For example:

https://jsfiddle.net/0ma8gdt2/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
    <select size="5">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    </select>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 2in;
  width: 1in;
}
```

But notice that the listbox does not extend to the bottom of the container, and the "size" attribute does not give us the ability to make it do that. So, how do I make the box extend all the way to the bottom of the container?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do this with [CSS flexboxes](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp):

https://jsfiddle.net/rov12uh4/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
    <select class="selector" size="2">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
    </select>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 2in;
  width: 1in;
}

.selector {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

The listbox behaves as desired even though there are technically more items than size=2 would otherwise allow.